# Insect crawling Identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

What kind of insect is this, and is this venomous, or dangerous? Don't need full species name just common name will do, color is red. Grandma always warned me of this, they usually are seen in monsoon season during heavy rains. They coil upwhen disturb .
Location: Country: India, lower himalayas
Google Map :[Exact location](https://www.google.com/maps/place/31%C2%B021%2716.7%22N+76%C2%B043%2757.5%22E/@31.354628,76.7304353,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!1m7!3m6!1s0x39053ed7e4902417:0xe7c41ae493267920!2sBeri+Darola,+Himachal+Pradesh!3b1!8m2!3d31.3451927!4d76.7437522!3m5!1s0x0:0x0!7e2!8m2!3d31.3546279!4d76.7326241!5m1!1e1)
A miniature version of this also exist in my area don't have pic though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the shape and the number of legs. That most definitely is not an *insect*. An insect has exactly 6 legs. No more, no less.

That critter in your picture is some kind of millipede (“a thousand feet”; not literally a thousand, of course; https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millipede), not to be confused with a centipede (“a hundred feet”; also not literally a hundred).

Millepedes are mostly harmless to humans. They eat things like dead plant matter or fungi. They sometimes also eat seedlings so they can be considered pests in gardens.

And given the colour, that’s *possibly* a rusty millipede (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigoniulus_corallinus). They have a very wide distribution around the Indo-Malayan region. Although there seems to be no recorded observation of it on iNaturalist around your region (https://www.inaturalist.org/observations?place_id=9248&taxon_id=123010).